# How to delete all WordPress authors who never posted?

Tags: sql, wordpress

Is there a way to delete all WordPress authors which have 0 posts?

Comment: Tad esoteric.  We could work up the SQL if we knew what tables were involved, and how they related to each other.

Comment: Um, don't close the question just because you don't like it, or you're not smart enough to answer it. This question fulfills the requirements of the FAQ...You might want to go and review it again: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @Robert: I didn't - the question doesn't belong superuser or serverfault, it just lacks detail for those of us who don't know the WordPress data model.

Comment: Agreed, some detail would be nice.  I don't have time ATM to go review the database design.

Answer (score 2):

To see each user and the number of posts of which he or she is the author:

```
select user_login, (select count(*) from wp_posts where post_author = wp_users.ID)
from wp_users
```

I'm not sure if it's safe to just delete rows from the `wp_users` table just because the user hasn't posted anything.  There may be references to the account from other tables.  It should, however, be safe to set the password:

```
update wp_users wp_users left join wp_posts on wp_users.ID = post_author
set user_pass = 'blocked'
where post_author is null
```

Comment: That's the question - how to keep the WP DB tables consistent when deleting users.

Comment: Combine that SQL to search and iterate over the results and use the `wp_delete_user` function to delete the user.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the admin panel and delete them?

Or do you have thousands to delete?

Comment: I literally have 1000s of users. It's not that my blog is very popular - but many of the users are automatically generated. So deleting them one by one is rather tedious.

Answer (score 0):

This will delete users (and their comments) who have not posted, except the admin.  If you delete user 1, your blog will be unusable.

DELETE FROM wp_comments 
WHERE user_id > 1 
  AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM wp_posts)

DELETE FROM wp_usermeta
WHERE user_id > 1 
  AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM wp_posts)

DELETE FROM wp_users
WHERE ID > 1 
  AND ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM wp_posts)